# Flutter page transition like IOS style (CupertinoPageTransitionBuilder()) in android

Tags: flutter, animation, routes, page-transition

How can I create a custom page animation like `CupertinoPageTransitionBuilder`. There are some work arounds like `stacking` **previous** and **new screen** and building animations that works when you move towards next while popping it shows the last stacked screen once and disappear after few milliseconds.

Any help would be great.

```
pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(), // NOT SO EFFECTIVE EITHER
      },
    ),
```

Stacking Current and next screen code.

```
Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: <Widget>[
        SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: const Offset(-0.3, 0.0),
          ).animate(animation),
          child: prevPage,
        ),

        SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(animation),
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animation,
            builder: (c, w) {
              return Material(
                shadowColor: Colors.black,
                // elevation: 10.0 * animation.value,
                child: nextPage
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

its update if you want to create a page transition animation where both the next and previous pages are animated simultaneously during the transition, you can consider using the `PageRouteBuilder` with a custom animation controller. This allows you to control the animations of both pages.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this effect:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FirstPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('First Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(_customPageRoute());
          },
          child: Text('Go to Second Page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  PageRouteBuilder _customPageRoute() {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
        return SecondPage();
      },
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        const begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
        const end = Offset.zero;
        const curve = Curves.easeInOut;
        var tween = Tween<Offset>(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

        var offsetAnimation = animation.drive(tween);

        var slideFromRight = SlideTransition(
          position: offsetAnimation,
          child: child,
        );

        var slideFromLeft = SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(-1.0, 0.0), end: Offset.zero).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve)).animate(animation),
          child: child,
        );

        return Stack(
          children: [
            slideFromRight,
            slideFromLeft,
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Second Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Text('Back to First Page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this code:

1. We use the `PageRouteBuilder` to create a custom page transition.
2. In the `transitionsBuilder`, we define two `SlideTransition` widgets for the incoming and outgoing pages. These transitions move the pages in opposite directions, creating the desired effect.
3. We use a `Stack` to overlay both pages during the transition.

This approach should create a simultaneous animation for both the next and previous pages during the transition. Adjust the `begin`, `end`, and `curve` values to fine-tune the animation effect to your liking.

Comment: Still not effect to exit screen https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135734 waiting for the response on this issue